# JS filter function. This argument

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Good Morning,

I've been trying some syntax on the filter function and I'm failing to understand why a specific case is not filtering.

Ultimate goal is  to get a range from my spreadsheet and use the function to pass a value to have filtered out on the range.

Following examples the code works fine

**---- (this correctly removes the value 6, resulting array is [0,5,8,0,88,0])**

```
{var range = [0,5,8,0,88,6,0]

function filtro (excl) {
  return excl != this;
}

var range = range.filter(filtro,6)}
```

---

**---- In the following code  i've moved the same array to a google sheets, and the code also correctly returns [0,5,8,0,88,0]**

```
  function advancedFilter(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testes");

  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A9").getValues();


  function filtro (excl) {
  return excl != 6;
}

  var range = range.filter(filtro)
}
```

---

**--- Yet, this last piece of code when I merge the two ideas above fails and returns [0,5,8,0,88,6,0], the range unchanged**

```
function advancedFilter(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testes");

  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A9").getValues();

  function filtro (excl) {
  return excl != this;
}

  var range = range.filter(filtro,6)
}
```

---

**Any hints?**

Comment: No value is returned from `advancedFilter()` call. What does  `console.log(range)`  log at last line of `advancedFilter` function? Why do you use `var range` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the [result of `sheet.getRange("A3:A9").getValues()` is an array of arrays of objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()). You say you're filtering the array `[0,5,8,0,88,6,0]` but its structure is actually an array of arrays with objects inside:  `[[new Number(0)],[new Number(5)],[new Number(8)],[new Number(0)],[new Number(88)],[new Number(6)],[new Number(0)]]`.

This explains why your `excl != 6` test correctly filters `[new Number(6)]`, because `[new Number(6)] != 6` is actually `false`. For non-strict comparison against a number primitive, the left-hand array turns into the string representation of its contents, which in this case is `"6"` (which is the string representation of `new Number(6)`). `"6"` is equal to `6` in non-strict comparison, so the inequality operation `!=` yields `false`.

The `excl != this` check fails because `filter` coerces its `thisArg` to an object, so it's like `new Number(6)`. Since the array and the `Number` object are both objects, JavaScript does no type coercion and simply checks if the same object is on both sides of the operator. In this case, they are two different objects, so the inequality operation `!=`  yields `true`.

- You can turn `this` back into a number primitive by using a unary `+` operator: `excl != +this`.
- Furthermore, you could do an even clearer comparison by pulling out the first element from the array being considered by filer (since your input is only one column anyway) and turn it into a primitive: `+excl[0] != +this`.
- Finally, since both sides are now a primitive, you can use a strict comparison: `+excl[0] !== +this`

Comment: Thanks. Very good and clear explanation. Learned a lot following the details on it. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If each item in the collection returned from `sheet.getRange("A3:A9").getValues();` is an object, then the tests will always fail because your `this` value will also be an object, and so it will be an identity comparison, which will fail.

To fix this, make `advancedFilter()` run in *strict mode*, so that your number `6` remains a primitive as the `this` value. That way the `==` will do its abstract comparison with coercion.

```
function advancedFilter() {  
  "use strict"; // <===== strict mode

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testes");

  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A9").getValues();

  function filtro (excl) {
    return excl != this; // `this` is a primitive instead of a `Number` object
  }

  var range = range.filter(filtro, 6);

  console.log(range);

  return range;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `this`, it's better to return a function.

```
function advancedFilter() {

var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testes");

var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A9").getValues(); 

function filtro (excl) { 
    return function (elem) {
        return elem != excl;
    }
} 

var range = range.filter(filtro(6));

}
```

Comment: That's an alternative, but doesn't really explain what's wrong with the code being asked about.